# Upload in heroku fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

i made this application and i wanted to host it.
I choose heroku But got following error during the build

> Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/build_dcf81a5e/index.js'

NOTE: i'm not using vue next react or any other kind of js i simply used **Node js**

If anyone wants the whole log please view these pics 
[Log part 1(Builds) https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSKbt.png]

[log part 2 (Error occurs)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8gL.png]

If required use my git repo for src
https://github.com/rohanCoderMan/AceBook
Package.json as follows

```json
  
{
  "name": "nodejsapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This is an app that we'll create showing off the basics of node.js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app",
    "build": "nodemon app"
  },
  "author": "rdzfinalrounduser",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect": "^3.7.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "flash": "^1.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.12",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

I have tried my best to keep this question clear if more info required please comment below(pls dont be harsh if i made a stupid mistake im just learning)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's defined in the build script in the package.json file?

Comment: See in the git repo

Comment: Dependencies are    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect": "^3.7.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "flash": "^1.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.12",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, check the heroku docs to see the deployment cycle. Basically, the build script is ran after installing the packages (this is typically for bundling the frontend code but sometimes also for compiling the server code like if you've used TypeScript). Since you don't have any build being done, you should take out that line in your `package.json` file. (Esentially, what you'd done here was start your server twice)

Also, Heroku has it's own process monitor so no need to use nodemon. Change the start script to `node app.js`. You could also add a dev script that uses nodemon for your local development, then you'd run it using `npm run dev`.

So in summary, change the scripts config in your package.json file to below:

```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "node app.js",
      "dev": "nodemon app.js",
  },
  ...
```

Also, you need to have an app.js file next to the package.json file which is where you write the code to start your server. Something that looks like [this file here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)